# Matlab: How to find values of properties of variables

Tags: matlab, object, properties

I have a matlab file, let's call i dataset.mat. When loading dataset.mat into workspace, it contains several variables, all these variables are objects defined as a class. Let's call these variables:

varObj1 varObj2 varObj3 ... varObjN

Now all these variables contain the properties that are defined in the object class. Let's say that varObj1 has the properties:

prop1 prop2 prop3 ... propM

All of these properties hold some value, either numbers, text or arrays.

I have lists of all the filenames of the varObj's and all the prop's: varObjList and propList.

The question is now: How to extract the values of all these properties in some automated way? I.e. make some sort of script that goes into each varObj and extracts each property of that object to another file, something like:

newFile = varObjList(i).propList(j)

To pick out the value of the j'th property of the i'th varObj?

Comment: "extracts each property of that object to another file": what kind of another file? please give a complete example with data of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: are you looking for the [`properties`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/properties.html) function?

Comment: I'd simply like to copy the value of a property into a new variable. Imagine the properties are Price1=1.25 and Price2=1,50, now I'd like to add these two numbers in a new variable called TotalPrice=2.75.

Comment: I have tried the properties function, let's say that Price1 and Price2 are properties of the object PriceList, then properties(PriceList) gives results 'Price1' and 'Price2', but not the values 1.25 and 1.50 that they are holding.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
vO1 = metaclass(varObj1);
pO1 = vO1.PropertyList;
pNames = {pO1.Name};
value1 = varObj1.(pNames{1})
```

And after reading Dan's comment, it's even simpler:

```
pNames = properties(varObj1);
value1 = varObj1.(pNames{1})
```

Comment: Thanks for yor idea, When writing the name of varObj1 out in full length, like value = NameOfVarObject1.(pNames{i}) actually does the trick. Now the problem is that the names of all the varObj's is on a list called varObjList, and the command value = varObjList(j).(pNames{i}) does NOT give the content of the i'th property of the j'th varObj.

Comment: what kind of list did you mean? if it is a cell array, you have to use `{}`, i.e `varObjList{j}.(pNames{i})`